# Cassandra performance for partial select of rows

Tags: cassandra, cql

If I have a cassandra table like the following

```
CREATE TABLE importantdata (
    a1 int,
    a2 int,
    a3 int,
    data1 blob,
    data2 blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (a1), a2, a3)
)
```

and then do a partial select

```
SELECT a1, a2, a3, data1 FROM importantdata WHERE a1=0 and a2=1 and a3<0
```

does the size of excluded the blob data2 play a factor in the performance of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On reads Cassandra will pull the whole row in memory, and sending back to the client (over the network) only the requested fields.

So, the excluded field, will play a factor in the performance since it won't be sent it back to the client, but the Cassandra nodes will put the whole row in memory when the query is executed.

Hope it helps,

Jose Luis